# OnTriggerEnter2D doesn't work at all. Unity This message parameter has to be type of Collider2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm apparently doing something wrong. Unity is giving me:

> Script error: OnTriggerEnter2D This message parameter has to be of
> type: Collider2D

I have a BoxCollider on an empty object that is a child of my player. When it collides nothing happens. I've set IsTrigger to true.

**Player's child script:**

```
public class EnemyHurtCollider : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Collider2D coll;
    private void Start()
    {
        GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerController>();
        rb = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        coll = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
    }
    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerController>().state = State.hurt; //state hurt
            if (other.gameObject.transform.position.x > transform.position.x)
            {
                Debug.Log("HURT");
                //if enemy is to my right when colliding I should be damaged and move left
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(-GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerController>().hurtForce, rb.velocity.y);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("HURT");
                //if enemy is to my left when colliding I should be damaged and move right
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerController>().hurtForce, rb.velocity.y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the correct signatures:

```
        private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D other)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

See what you did? you mixed up the function `OnTriggerEnter2D` but you're passing the parameter for `OnCollisionEnter2D`.

So change: `public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collision2D other)` to `private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)`

Comment: Thanks alot! My bad that I didn't check the signatures.